# How to diff file names in two directories (without writing to intermediate files)?

Tags: diff, filenames, ls

I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
diff `ls -1a ./dir1` `ls -1a ./dir2`
```

But that doesn't work for obvious reasons. Is there a better way of achieving this (in 1 line), than this?

```
ls -1a ./dir1 > lsdir1
ls -1a ./dir2 > lsdir2
diff lsdir1 lsdir2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You were close. In bash you want [**process substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), not command substitution:

```
diff <(ls -1a ./dir1) <(ls -1a ./dir2)
```

Comment: Process substitution is not necessary, though. The answer below (https://superuser.com/a/228773/566289) is on point!

Comment: Except that answer diffs the content, not the filenames!

Answer (score 13):

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
```

using the -r option, walk entire directory trees, recursively checking differences between subdirectories and files that occur at comparable points in each tree. The trick is to use the -q option to suppress line-by-line comparisons

Comment: @festo : You wree missing the poitn of this question, I don't actually want to diff the contents of the files, I want to diff the output of the `ls` commands

Comment: +1, Actually, I got the same output with the one caveat, diff -rq reported a linked file as 'No such file or directory'. So, plus one for correct, and frankly simpler usage. (even if IVA's answer is a better 'learning opportunity' for process substitution (>_<)

Comment: This is *much* slower than diffing the file names: the entirety of every file has to be read and compared.

Comment: @Josh of course, because it does recursively....

Comment: @Braiam: Even if you recursively diff the file names (using `rsync` with the `--dry-run` option, for example), it would still be much faster than `diff -r`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither answers did the work for me as :

1. I needed the diff to be recursive
2. My folders were not side by side

Inspired from @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I used :

> diff <(find PATH1 | sed 's"PATH1""') <(find PATH2 | sed 's"PATH2""')

Which does the job just fine and can be adapted for a nifty script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage : compDirs dir1 dir2
# compare the file/folder names recursively in Dir1 and Dir2
 
PATH1=$1 
PATH2=$2

diff <(find $PATH1 | sed "s#$PATH1##") <(find $PATH2 | sed "s#$PATH2##")
```

Comment: A variant without sed would be `diff <(cd $PATH1 && find .) <(cd $PATH2 && find .)`. As these are subprocesses the cd won't propagate to parent processes.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [this](https://superuser.com/a/228770/158220), since I don't have enough points to comment, the options `-y` (to show in two columns) and `--suppress-common-lines` make it even better!

`diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(ls -1a ./dir1) <(ls -1a ./dir2)`

You can remove `-a` from `ls` parts if not interested in dot/hidden files.